# Assign multiple parameters to properties in PHP

Tags: php, class, constructor

I have a class definition like such:

```
class User{
    public $first;
    public $last;
    public $email;
    public $guid;
    public $website;
    public $bio;
    public $picture;
    public $gender;
    ...
}
```

and a constructor that takes values from factory functions and puts them in the class, like so:

```
public function __construct($guid, $first , $last,$email, $bio, $picture, $gender) {
    $this->guid = $guid;
    $this->first = $first;
    $this->last = $last;
    $this->email = $email;
            ...
}
```

Is there a simple method that will auto-assign all these variables?
Or can I loop through them all using a for with PHP's parameter functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be simpler in such case:

```
class User{

    public function __construct($params) {//params is array('first' => 'hello', 'last' => 'hi', 'email'=>'hellohi@hi.com')
        foreach ($params as $key => $value)
        {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then access properties as:

```
$params = array('first' => 'hello', 'last' => 'hi', 'email'=>'hellohi@hi.com');
$user = new User($params);
echo $user->first;
```

Comment: That won't work very well, because I want to be able to access the properties outside of the class. I can just use my original approach, but I was wondering if there is something more efficient.

Comment: properties can then be accessed via $params array 
like echo $obj->params['first'];

Comment: Yeah I know, but I'd rather just use $obj->first. If no one can answer this, I might as well close this thread and just use the original (albeit verbose) way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class User {

    public $first;
    public $last;
    public $email;
    public $guid;
    public $website;
    public $bio;
    public $picture;
    public $gender;


    public function __construct($params) { // Same params array from previous answer.

        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {

            $this->$key = $value;
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I still think there must be something simpler... Some method tucked away in PHP for just this type of thing.

Comment: If you find something simpler, post it here, we're all curious! :)

Comment: There is a function called `func_get_args` you can use to get all the parameters passed to a function, as an array, but it's not an associative array. It's simply returning a numbered array with the parameters in the order they were passed.

Comment: Actually, that might work because the function takes these paramaters in a particular order. I just dont understand how to use the properties as a numeric array.

Comment: You can't. You need to use their names.

Answer (score 0):

Using func_get_args as suggested by Simon Germain and using the list function you get :

```
<?php 

class Test{

    var $x, $y, $z;

    function __construct($x, $y, $z){
         list($this->x, $this->y, $this->z) = func_get_args();
    }
 }
```

I don't believe it can be done in a shorter way.